# ASP.NET Table control - save button postback loses all my rows and cells

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a ASP.NET Table control which I have dragged to my page. I have to create the rows and columns dynamically which I have also done. Some of the cells in my table are textboxes. I want to be able to modify the textbox values and save the changes. I have added a button within the same panel as the table but when I try to loop through the tables rows I get zero.

Why is the table not remembering my rows and cells?  As I have already loaded the data once I don't want to rebuild the table each time a button is pressed. I think by creating the table each time in Page_Load I'd be going back and forth to the database server. I really want to avoid this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your dynamically created table in view that you can fetch after rendering.

```
SqlConnection con =new  SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbstring"].ConnectionString);

private int ctrName = 0;
Table tableName = null;  

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        tableName = new Table();
        tableName.ID = "tableName";
        Session["tableName"] = tableName;
        ViewState["ctrName"] = ctrName;
    }
    ctrName = (Int32)ViewState["ctrName"];
    tableName = (Table)Session["tableName"];
    pnlName.Controls.Add(tableName);
}
private void GenerateName()
{
    ctrName++;
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.ID = "Txt_Name" + ctrName;
    tb.Width = 150;
    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
    tableName.Rows.Add(row);
    Session["tableName"] = tableName;
    ViewState["ctrName"] = ctrName;
}
```

For Access the table details:

```
tableName = (Table)Session["tableName"];
```

Comment: Adding the table to the Session worked. Although I haven't tested it completely I think this is probably the method I need to use.  BTW in your example why are you using the ViewState? It looks like Session is sufficient. Thanks for your help.